# Tukey's Test HSD.TEST interaction output is null.

Tags: anova, tukey

I have a question regarding  a means separation test to test interactions. Is it possible to perform a Tukey's Test with interactions? One of my terms in my model is significant and I want to know which ones they are.

```
  For example my model is 
  ModelB<- lm(RATING.2~Allele%in%QTL11.Source+Family%in%QTL11.Source+REP)
  anova(ModelB)

Response: RATING.2
                      Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F) 

REP                   2   1.301  0.6507  0.9266    0.3993    
Allele:QTL11.Source   8 105.021 13.1276 18.6941 < 2.2e-16 ***
QTL11.Source:Family  37  68.644  1.8552  2.6419 6.873e-05 ***
Residuals           100  70.223  0.7022                      
---

TukeysTestB<- HSD.test(ModelB,"Allele%in%QTL11.Source")
TukeysTestB
NULL
```

Why am I getting a NULL output, Is this not possible to test?